# Sonar Runner execution gives 100% compliance with the rules

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Upon launching Sonar Runner, the execution is successful.
But the result gives 100% compliance, which shouldn't be the case for my project

Sonar-runner.properties:

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

#----- Global database settings
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar

#----- Default source code encoding
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

Versions being used:

SonarQube:3.7.3;
Sonnarrunner:2.3

Project language:c++

OS: Windows 7

Comment: Are you using the commercial C++ plugin or the community one?

Comment: community plugin :sonar-cxx-plugin-0.9.jar